# Problema con codigo de javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo una pequeña duda, soy nuevo en esto de la programacion web, y estoy siguiendo un curso por youtube y tengo un pequeño problema con el codigo, que no se ejecuta como en el video. a pesar de estar todo bien escrito, el curso es del 2014, asi que imagino que algo ha ambiado desde entonces y por lo tanto me da el error...
Adjunto el codigo...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Primera web Javascript</title>
        
        <script src="archivo script.js"></script>
        <style> .importante{color:#DD272A} </style>
        
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <p class="importante">Estamos estudiando javascript</p>
        <p>ejemplo 1</p>
        <p>ejemplo 2</p>
        <p>javascript</p>
    </body>
</html>





// JavaScript Document

function ejecuta(){
    

    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].onclick=saludo();}


function saludo(){  
    
    alert("Hola, que hay de nuevo");
    
}

window.onload=ejecuta();
```

Se supone que al cargar la pagina deberia ejecutarse la funcion "ejecuta" el cual al darle click al primer parrafo, deberia saltar una alerta en ventana emergente. Lo cual no es asi, la alerta salta a la vista apenas carga la pagina y no al presionar el parrafo...

Agradeceria la ayuda, ya que soy nuevo en esto del desarrollo web.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con codigo de javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/381565/problema-con-codigo-de-javascript)

Comment: No dupliques la pregunta por favor

Comment: Perdon, no me fije que se habia duplicado

Comment: window.onload=ejecuta;
sin parentesis.

Comment: Si le quito los parentersis, no me reconoce la funcion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en los paréntesis como te escribieron en los comentarios de tu pregunta duplicada.

¿Pero cuáles paréntesis?

Ten presente lo siguiente:

- Cuando declaras una función, debe tener paréntesis `function ejecuta(){...}`
- Cuando quieres ejecutar una función, debes colocarle paréntesis `ejecuta();`
- Cuando asignas una función a una variable (o como manejador de evento en este caso) NO le pongas paréntesis (porque se ejecuta)

En las líneas:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].onclick=...;

window.onload=...;
```

Tanto `.onclick` como `.onload` son eventos a los que les quieres asignar la función que se va a ejecutar cuando el evento ocurra, en estos casos va sin parentesis.

De esta forma, el Javascript corregido quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
function ejecuta(){
    //                             sin parentesis  |
    //                                             V 
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].onclick=saludo;
}


function saludo(){  
    
    alert("Hola, que hay de nuevo");
    
}


//  sin parentesis  |
//                  V 
   window.onload=ejecuta;
```

Comment: Modifique el codigo tal cual lo mencionaste, sin los parentesis, y tampoco hace la funcion, si bien ya no sale la alerta al cargar la pagina, no se ejecuta tampoco al hacer click en el parrafo. por cierto, utilizo la ultima version de dreamweaver, no se si afecta en algo

Comment: Acabo de destacar los lugares donde no van los parentesis y asegurate que tu archivo de javascript realmente se llame `archivo script.js` y que esté ubicado en la misma carpeta del HTML. Te sugiero utilizar nombres de archivos sin espacios.

Comment: Verifique el nombre, y en efecto, se llama asi el archivo, y esta en la misma carpeta, y sigue sin correr el codigo :/

Comment: Eso es extraño, en las pruebas que hice funciona haciendo click en el texto **ejemplo 1**. Tanto el HTML como el JS los copie y guardé con el block de notas y los probé con Chrome, Firefox y Opera y funciona en todos. De Dreamweaver no te puedo decir nada porque, aunque se de su existencia, nunca he trabajado con el.

Comment: El problema estaba en el dreamweaver, la vista previa no me corria la alerta, tuve que ejecutar el archivo directo de la carpeta. 

Gracias por tomarte la molestia de responderme la pregunta